# Access Database ConnectionString

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

I use access in C# app and my app work in my pc.
when run app at other device, the app can't connect to database.
access2010 install on all deivces and my pc.
my VisualStadio is 2015 and .net version 4.6
this is my connectionString

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Is this a console app?

Comment: i hav'nt error log but app cant connect to access. connection string :Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|ContractDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=True

Comment: no ,windows app

Comment: @Hilex I get that but is it a web app or a console app? Do you have a web.config/appsettings.json or app.config?

Comment: yes i have app.config

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    </startup>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="AccessDB" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|ContractDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: You need to add the code you're running and any errors you receive when you run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i installed [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) but problem not resolved
then I installed [office data Connectivity Driver](https://download.cnet.com/2007-Office-System-Driver-Data-Connectivity-Components/3000-10254_4-75452798.html) and problem **solved**.

Answer (score 1):

Check interope library added in your nuget. On your machine it's there so oledb connection establish. If not present on other machine it will not establish connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your executing assembly in order for your app to pick up the app.config within the correct assembly:

```
var path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
var connStr = config.AppSettings.Settings["AccessDB"].Value;
```